# How to navigate different pages according to selected item in combo box when submit button is clicked in php

Tags: php, html

I have two combo boxes one is Category and the other one is City,according to what i select from combo box i need to navigate to different pages when submit button is clicked.

ex: If the selected item in combo box is Cars I need to navigate to cars.html page if the selected item is Bikes I need to navigate to bike.html page when submit button is clicked.

This is a part of my code,

```
     <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]; ?>" method="post">

            <div id="absolute">
                <h1><b>Select a category & a City </b></h1>

                <table class="spacingTable" width="600">
                    <tr>
                        <td><label name="category">Category</label></td>
                        <td>
                        <select id="cmb1" name="Category">
                            <option value="select">Please select a Category</option>
                            <option value="Cars">Cars</option>
                            <option value="mbikes">Motorbikes & Scooters</option>
                            <option value="threewheelers">Three Wheelers</option>
                            <option value="van">Vans & Busses</option>
                            <option value="hvd">Heavy-Duty vehicles</option>

                        </select></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>

                        <td><label name="City">City</label></td>
                        <td>
                        <input type="text" id="textbox1" name="city">
                        </td>

                        <td>
                        <div id="div-ok">
                            <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Ok">
                        </div></td>

                    </tr>

                </table>

            </div>
        </form>

    </body>
this is php code snippet
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){
    if(!empty($_POST['Category'])){

    // redirect the user to cars.html or mbikes.html
    header("Location: " . $_POST['Category'] . ".html");
    exit();
    }
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Javascript** solution:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="#">
        <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <select name="category" id="category">
                    <option value="cars">Cars</option>
                    <option value="mbikes">Motorbikes & Scooters</option>
                </select>
            </td>

            <td>
                <div id="div-ok">
                    <input type="submit" value="Ok" id="goTo">
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
    </form>

<script>

document.getElementById('goTo').onclick = function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var page = document.getElementById('category').value,
        extension = '.html';

    window.location = category + extension;
}

</script>
```

Comment: Can you please explain little bit about what happens in this code, then i'll be able to get some idea , then i can modify the code according to my requirement.

Comment: I added IDs to some HTML elements and added javascript code at the end. When you click the button (now called "goTo"), window.location (url of website) changes to yourPath+yourPage. yourPath is irrelevant here.. it could be used if you have another folders. yourPage is the selected option of the category.. I should named it "yourCategory" instead of "yourPage".

Comment: my vehicle.php that means this code is located in the desktop inside a folder so i changed my code like this is it correct or not? However still i;m not getting the output.<script>
  document.getElementById('goTo').onclick = function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();

   var yourPath = '/', 
   var yourPage = document.getElementById('cmb1').value;
   var pathToFolder = 'file:///C:/Users/Siyumi/Desktop/VehicleWebsite';
   
   window.location = pathToFolder + yourPath + yourPage ;
  }

 </script>

Comment: <script>
  document.getElementById('goTo').onclick = function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();

   var yourPath = '/', 
   var yourPage = document.getElementById('cmb1').value;
   var pathToFolder = 'file:///C:/Users/Siyumi/Desktop/VehicleWebsite';
   
   window.location = pathToFolder + yourPath + yourPage ;
  }

 </script>

Comment: here it is not clear so i put my edited code above I'm in a trouble with this qustion for two days If you give me some idea i'm really grateful to you

Comment: Go to the chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101142/discussion-between-crash-programmer-and-esjuanma

Answer (score 1):

In a nutshell you can do something like this:

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]; ?>" method="post">
    <table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <select name="category">
                <option value="cars">Cars</option>
                <option value="mbikes">Motorbikes & Scooters</option>
            </select>
        </td>

        <td>
            <div id="div-ok">
                <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Ok">
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

And process the form like this:

```
if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){
    if(!empty($_POST['category'])){

        // redirect the user to cars.html or mbikes.html        
        header("Location: " . $_POST['category'] . ".html");
        exit();
    }
}
```

Here are the relevant references:

- [`header()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)
- [`exit()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php)

Comment: Can you please explain me a bit about what happens in $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] variable

Comment: @CrashProgrammer From [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php), `$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]` is used to get the filename of the currently executing script. I used `$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]` in this example to submit and process the form in the same php file. You can specify your own filename  in place of `$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];` , where you want to process the form, like `<form action="somepage.php" method="post">`

Answer (score 0):

$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] is the filename of your form, so, when you submit the form, it points to the self page.
To make it work, you have to put the **Rajdeep Paul's** php code at the beginning of the form file, in top of everything else.
The result would look like this:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){
        if(!empty($_POST['category'])){

            // redirect the user to cars.html or mbikes.html        
            header("Location: " . $_POST['category'] . ".html");
            exit();
        }
    }
?>

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]; ?>" method="post">
        <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <select name="category">
                    <option value="cars">Cars</option>
                    <option value="mbikes">Motorbikes & Scooters</option>
                </select>
            </td>

            <td>
                <div id="div-ok">
                    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Ok">
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
    </form> 
</body>
</html>
```

I just took **Rajdeep Paul's** code and edited it to be easier to you.

Comment: I just copied this code snippet to my code but it's not giving me the answer what will be the wrong ? can you please give me a solution

Comment: I tested it and it works fine.. how did you name your file? (including the extension)

Comment: I named it as Vehicle.html and it located in desktop inside a folder is that matters here

Comment: I put my entire code above please give me a solution for this I'm a beginner to php

Comment: You have to name it as Vehicle.php. It won't work on your computer (unless you have wamp or xamp installed, but I guess you don't), but it will work fine on your hosting. If you want to make it work on your computer you should do it with javascript. If you know a little of javascript you could do that changing the window.location. See: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_location.asp

Comment: I have insatalled xampp in my computer :-(

Comment: I left a javascript solution for what you want to achieve. You may make some modifications to polish it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101142/discussion-between-crash-programmer-and-esjuanma).